# Excel 2010: VLOOKUP with multiple result

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have the following data:

**Example**:

```
    A             B               C
EmployeeID   EmployeeName   EmployeeSalary
-------------------------------------------
E101         JAK            20000
E102         SAM            25000
E103         John           20000
E104         Shawn          30000
```

I have the cell `H1` in which i type salary of the employee, and in the below cell that is cell `H2, I2, J2` should list the employee details according to the given salary in the cell `H1`.

I have used `VLOOKUP` function for this.

For cell H2:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H1,C2:A5,1,FALSE),"EmployeeID not found")
```

For cell I2:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H1,C2:B4,2,FALSE),"EmployeeName not found")
```

For cell J2:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H1,C2:C4,3,FALSE),"EmployeeSalary not found")
```

**Note**: The above works fine for single result to display but when i enter `20000` it will only show single record NOT all which meet the given criteria.

Comment: This would be a great use of Advanced Filter.

Comment: you cant left search using excel either, I would suggest using INDEX(MATCH())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to deal with this:

First the Formula:

I set up the Field as such which will become apparent with another method:

[image]

So in J4 I put the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,6,$C$2:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1E+99,C:C))/($C$2:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1E+99,C:C))=$H$2),ROW(1:1)),"")
```

In H4 I put:

```
=IF($J4<>"",INDEX(A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,$C:$C)),AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($C$2:INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(1E+99,$C:$C)))-1)/($C$2:INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(1E+99,$C:$C))=$J4),COUNTIF($J$4:$J4,$J4))),"")
```

Which I then drag across to I4.  Then drag all three formulas down till you are sure you have covered all the possible results.

This is a non CSE array formula.  Array formulas calculations are exponential, so we need to limit the reference range to the minimum needed.  All the `INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(1E+99,$C:$C))` finds the last cell with data and sets this as the end reference.

The `IFERROR()` wrapper on the first allows the formula to be copied down further than the list will return and avoid the `#N/A`.  In the picture the formulas occupy the first 8 rows.

[image]

---

Second we use the Advanced Filter:

First we set up the area around H1 like this:

[image]

Then we navigate to Advanced Filter which is on the Data tab.  This window pops open:

[image]

Then we enter the Information:

Mark the Copy to another location.
List Range is `$A$1:$C$5`
Criteria Range is `$A$1:$C$5`
Copy to range is `$H$3:$J$3`

[image]

Then hit okay.

[image]

---

The third is vba which mimic the Advanced Filter:

```
Sub atfilt()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim critrng As Range
Dim cpytorng As Range
Dim lstrow As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet9")
lstrow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Set rng = ws.Range("A1:C" & lstrow)
Set critrng = ws.Range("H1:H2")
Set cpytorng = ws.Range("H3:J3")

rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=critrng, CopyToRange:=cpytorng, Unique:=False
End Sub
```

---

Each has their disadvantages:

Formula: If the data set is large then(1,000 rows or more) the calculations will be long.

Advanced Filter: Each step must be redone each time a new filter is wanted.  It is not automatic.

VBA: It is VBA and requires a certain understanding on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Scott Craner's comment that autofilter would be great here to allow you to find multiple values based on a criteria. Unfortunately (maybe someone can fill this bit in :)) I don't know much about autofilter in vba for this purpose (only used it once or twice)

I can tell you about left lookups with INDEX(MATCH()) which should work in place of your VLOOKUPS.

**Format:**

**INDEX(**"column of values to return"**,MATCH(**"lookup value"**,**"column to find lookup value"**, 0))**

so in your example for cell H2 you could use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(H1,$C:$C,0)),"EmployeeID not found")
```

Note the "0" in the formula is to find an exact match!

Comment: This will still only pull the first one that matches.  The OP stated that what was wanted was all that match not just the first one.  For a formula answer this will need to incorporate a LARGE or SMALL function.

Comment: aaaaahhhhhhhhhhh! I understand, more work needed here then :)

Comment: wait, couldn't OP use a vba loop that loops through all cells in a range and if the cell matches the criteria of H1 it adds cell.value to an array or table or whatever?

Comment: Yes they can.  But again you are then reinventing the Advanced filter which will take criteria and copy those that match and paste them in a different area.